# ArrayFilter is failing to match any elements

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a simple web forum system and i've come across this problem when trying to give the users a way to post messages to a thread. Each thread is a document inside an array in a group document, and then inside each thread document is a message array which should contain message documents.

My query is:

```
 db.grops.update({},{$push:{"threads.$[elem].messages":"hello"}},{arrayFilters:[{"elem._id":ObjectId("602645582fa6cb13f8449057")}]})
```

And my group table of the db is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60264286f5440e114c189212"),
    "members" : [ ],
    "name" : "Computer Science London",
    "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [
                    51.503391,
                    -0.12763
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("60264286f5440e114c189213"),
            "type" : "Point"
    },
    "description" : "A group for computing students to learn, talk and share!",
    "pictureURL" : "/images/computer.jpg",
    "threads" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("602645582fa6cb13f8449057"),
                    "title" : "What is a lambda function",
                    "openingPost" : "I am reading this textbook and it mentions this thing called a lambda function, but it doesnt seem to outline what it is. Can someone help me understand?",
                    "postedBy" : "ElBarto88",
                    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T09:07:36.833Z"),
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T09:07:36.833Z"),
                    "messages" : [ ]
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("602645af2fa6cb13f8449058"),
                    "title" : "How do i install linux?",
                    "openingPost" : "This server assignment requires i have linux installed, how do install it?",
                    "postedBy" : "ElBarto88",
                    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T09:09:03.123Z"),
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T09:09:03.123Z"),
                    "messages" : [ ]
            }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T08:55:34.273Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-02-12T09:09:03.123Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I can not seem to get any query to get any matches, and then push "hello" to the sub-array. I have also tried matching by `{"elem.postedBy:"ElBarto88"}`, to no avail. For all the queries involving arrayFilters i get back:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Currently i am just testing by posting the queries directly to the mongo shell(i am using mongoose for the main application). My shell version is: v4.4.2 , and my server version (MongoDB atlas cluster) is:  v4.4.3

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this:

```
db.grops.update({"threads.$._id":ObjectId("602645582fa6cb13f8449057")},{$push:{"threads.$.messages":"hello"}})
```

Let me know if it doesn't work. Remember: it wil update ONLY FIRST matching element.

Comment: i am still getting `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`, it's really puzulling me , i wonder if it's a problem with my server. I can't figure this out i guess the most sensible option will be to put threads or messages into their own collections.

Comment: @Lightningz1 I has updated my answer. Please check again

Comment: Still not working. The mongoDB documentation says "Starting in MongoDB 4.4, the $ projection operator can only appear at the end of the field path; e.g. "field.$" or "fieldA.fieldB.$"." so i didnt try that route. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) But thank you very much for helping anyway

Answer (score 0):

I've been really stupid, it was a spelling mistake causing my problems. `group` not `grop`, not the code.

*facepalms and closes thread quickly*